Collect values as dictionary in parent column using Pyspark
I have code and data like below:
df_renamed = df.withColumnRenamed("id","steps.id").withColumnRenamed("status_1","steps.status").withColumnRenamed("severity","steps.error.severity")

df_renamed.show(truncate=False)

+----------+-------+------+-----------------------+------------+--------------------+
|apiVersion|expired|status|steps.id               |steps.status|steps.error.severity|
+----------+-------+------+-----------------------+------------+--------------------+
|2         |false  |200   |mexican-curp-validation|200         |null                |
+----------+-------+------+-----------------------+------------+--------------------+  

Now I want to transform this data as below:
+----------+-------+------+-----------------------+------------+--------------------+
|apiVersion|expired|status|steps                                                    |
+----------+-------+------+-----------------------+------------+--------------------+
|2         |false  |200   |{"id":"mexican-curp-validation", "status":200 ,"error":{"severity":null}}               |
+----------+-------+------+-----------------------+------------+--------------------+  

where it can be seen that based on the dot notation of the column names, JSON struct is formed in the data. For this reason, I used below code:
cols_list = [name for name in df_renamed.columns if "." in name]
df_new = df_renamed.withColumn("steps",F.to_json(F.struct(*cols_list)))
df_new.show()   

But it gives below error even though the column is present:
 df_new = df_renamed.withColumn("steps",F.to_json(F.struct(*cols_list)))
  File "/Users/../IdeaProjects/pocs/venvsd/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 3036, in withColumn
    return DataFrame(self._jdf.withColumn(colName, col._jc), self.sparkSession)
  File "/Users/../IdeaProjects/pocs/venvsd/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/Users/../IdeaProjects/pocs/venvsd/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 196, in deco
    raise converted from None
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Column 'steps.id' does not exist. Did you mean one of the following? [steps.id, expired, status, steps.status, apiVersion, steps.error.severity];
'Project [apiVersion#17, expired#18, status#19, steps.id#29, steps.status#37, steps.error.severity#44, to_json(struct(id, 'steps.id, status, 'steps.status, severity, 'steps.error.severity), Some(GMT+05:30)) AS steps#82]
+- Project [apiVersion#17, expired#18, status#19, steps.id#29, steps.status#37, severity#22 AS steps.error.severity#44]
   +- Project [apiVersion#17, expired#18, status#19, steps.id#29, status_1#21 AS steps.status#37, severity#22]
      +- Project [apiVersion#17, expired#18, status#19, id#20 AS steps.id#29, status_1#21, severity#22]
         +- Relation [apiVersion#17,expired#18,status#19,id#20,status_1#21,severity#22] csv

Where am I going wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Special characters in column names can be escaped using back ticks in the name"`" as follows
cols_list = ["`" + name + "`" for name in df1.columns if "." in name]

So that when you refer to it inside the to_json function then it will be "step.id" which successfully escapes the "." character
Be careful when dealing with column names that contain any special characters and I would recommend to avoid it if possible.

But this resolves my 1st level nested cols. It doesn't help with further nested levels.

You can get the same output without renaming the columns using struct and to_json:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = [(2, False, 200, "mexican-curp-validation", 200, None)]
schema = "apiVersion int, expired string, status int, id string, status_1 int, severity string"
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df.show(truncate=False)

# +----------+-------+------+-----------------------+--------+--------+
# |apiVersion|expired|status|id                     |status_1|severity|
# +----------+-------+------+-----------------------+--------+--------+
# |2         |false  |200   |mexican-curp-validation|200     |NULL    |
# +----------+-------+------+-----------------------+--------+--------+

cols_list = F.struct(
    F.col("id"),
    F.col("status_1").alias("status"),
    F.struct(F.col("severity")).alias("error")
)
df_transformed = df.withColumn("steps", F.to_json(cols_list)).drop("id", "status_1", "severity")
df_transformed.printSchema()
df_transformed.show(truncate=False)

# root
#  |-- apiVersion: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- expired: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- status: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- steps: string (nullable = true)

# +----------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
# |apiVersion|expired|status|steps                                                   |
# +----------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
# |2         |false  |200   |{"id":"mexican-curp-validation","status":200,"error":{}}|
# +----------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+

The reason you are not seeing severity is because of None - to_json won't include the nulls.
Here's the confirmation that the schema is intact - just convert the None to string for testing:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = [(2, False, 200, "mexican-curp-validation", 200, "None")]
schema = "apiVersion int, expired string, status int, id string, status_1 int, severity string"
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

cols_list = F.struct(
    F.col("id"),
    F.col("status_1").alias("status"),
    F.struct(F.col("severity")).alias("error")
)
df_transformed = df.withColumn("steps", F.to_json(cols_list)).drop("id", "status_1", "severity")

df_transformed.show(truncate=False)

# +----------+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |apiVersion|expired|status|steps                                                                    |
# +----------+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |2         |false  |200   |{"id":"mexican-curp-validation","status":200,"error":{"severity":"None"}}|
# +----------+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+


Is it possible to do it more dynamically? Because I have a huge schema. Also, in my actual data if its Null then I can't convert it to a string anyways. Then how is this gonna work?

Even if its null, I want something like {"severity":null}
